# Shortest way (one-liner) to get a default argument out of a v8 function?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

It's been a long time since I've used C++, and even longer since I wrapped my head around hard types. I'm simply looking for a **working** one liner to do get an argument from v8, or a default value when an argument wasn't supplied.

```
v8::String::Utf8Value arg0(args[0]);
v8::String::Utf8Value arg1(args[1]);
v8::String::Utf8Value arg2(args[2]);
const char *username = (args.Length() > 0) ? *arg0 : "";
const char *password = (args.Length() > 1) ? *arg1 : "";
const char *service = (args.Length() > 2) ? *arg2 : "login";
```

Outputs:

```
func(); // { username: "", password: "", service: "login" }
func('1'); // { username: "1", password: "", service: "login" }
func('1', '2'); // { username: "1", password: "2", service: "login" }
func('a', 'b', 'c'); // { username: "a", password: "b", service: "c" }
```

Unfortunately, the following close-to-ideal solution doesn't work for me (any ideas why?):

```
const char *username = (args.Length() > 0) ? *v8::String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString()) : "";
const char *password = (args.Length() > 1) ? *v8::String::Utf8Value(args[1]->ToString()) : "";
const char *service = (args.Length() > 2) ? *v8::String::Utf8Value(args[2]->ToString()) : "login";
```

Comment: I'll admit I don't know too much about v8, but your replacement looks mighty suspicious from a C++ POV to me: when do arg0/arg1/arg2's destructors run? When do those destructors run in your one-liner? What happens to the allocated memory when the class's destructor is run?

Comment: Hah, oh God... so afaik (aside from the fact that everything in v8 is static and horrible for memory management because it's a JS engine which needs access to everything everywhere): args *might* be destroyed once my function returns... but.. it's very possible that v8 hangs on to the data for its internal "stack tracing". Basically, I don't know positively, I'll definitely be profiling the code when it's finished. ;)

Comment: Convoluted one liners aren't exactly the "cleanest" solutions.

Comment: Shortest then. Question fixed.

Comment: Generate the bindings. Stop caring about silly stuff like this. Problem solved. Also you probably want to be working with `std::string`, not `const char*`.

Comment: @CalebGray: it's not `args` that are being destroyed but temporary `Utf8Value` which contains inside a temporary C-string. When `Utf8Value` is destroyed pointer returned by `Utf8Value::operator*` becomes invalid.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `char *`s instead of `std::string`s?

Comment: I'm not using `std:string` because I don't need anything it provides. `strcpy` does everything I needed to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vyacheslav Egorov nailed it with his comment, by the time I was accessing the string, it had been destroyed. Ultimately I ended up using:

```
char *get(v8::Local<v8::Value> value, const char *fallback = "") {
    if (value->IsString()) {
        v8::String::AsciiValue string(value);
        char *str = (char *) malloc(string.length() + 1);
        strcpy(str, *string);
        return str;
    }
    char *str = (char *) malloc(strlen(fallback) + 1);
    strcpy(str, fallback);
    return str;
}
```

Usage Example:

```
v8::Handle<v8::Value> myMethod(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    char *username = get(args[0], "user");
    char *password = get(args[1], "pass");

    ...
}
```

Comment: P.S. I'll accept a better answer than my own. I really hate answering my own questions.

Answer (score 3):

This bit of code worked well for me for extracting a string value from a v8 value in one line:

```
std::string tempString(*v8::String::Utf8Value(args[someInteger]));
```

The std::string constructor should handle your default scenarios without need for additional code, but if you do need to manually check for null values, this is trivial.

This code serves as an example, it gets string values of all the arguments and prints them to stdout, and of course puts them into a nice array, because what use is printing them out?

```
std::string* printAllArgs(const Arguments& args){
    std::cout << "PRINTING ALL ARGS: ";
    std::string* stringArray = new std::string[args.Length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < args.Length(); i++){
        std::string tempString(*v8::String::Utf8Value(args[i]));
        stringArray[i] = tempString;
        std::cout << tempString << ";";
    }
    return stringArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Egorov  is correct in that the temporary `AsciiValue` object has been auto-destroyed like a smart pointer in the compact notation:

```
const char *username = *v8::String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString());
//transient AsciiValue object has gone out of scope, and its destructor has been called in
//  previous line, rendering the pointer (content) invalid henceforth!
...
```

This is because the `AsciiValue` has gone out of scope in that single-line scope.

Instead, should break it up into 2 lines if you intend to use the 'cached' pointer several times:

```
{
  v8::String::Utf8Value usernameObj(args[0]->ToString());
  const char *username = *usernameObj;
  ...
  //use username pointer as often as desired; it remains valid in this entire scope.
  doSomethingWithString(username); //OK

  //can also dereference Utf8Value object only when needed:
  doSomethingWithString(*usernameObj); //OK
}
//here, usernameObj is out of scope and is destroyed, and username will become invalid.
```

If only intending to use the string value once, it is still perfectly OK to use the compact notation:

```
doSomethingWithString(*v8::String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString())); //OK
```

The `doSomethingWithString` function gets the correct value to work with. Only upon returning from it, then the `Utf8Value` if auto-destroyed.

Same thing happens for String::AsciiValue.

Answer (score 0):

```
string bi = info[0]->IsUndefined() ? "backwardIndex.dat" : string(*Nan::Utf8String(info[0]));
```